# Trouble putting ads on Android Application

Tags: android

I'm trying to put ads on my app before I put my app on the app store.

I followed a tutorial here >>> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#load_the_ad_in_the_mainactivity_class <<<

I'm getting an error when I launch:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here is my code:

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Fact App</string>
    <string name="settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="about">About</string>
    <string name="rate">Rate us!</string>
    <string name="home">Home</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id"> ca-app-pub-1257847978838563/3917394334</string>
</resources>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**MainActivity**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextBox);
        factNumberBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberBox);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the following gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error when I run it.                                   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: I would try cleaning and rebuilding your project and also restarting Android Studio.

Comment: Ugh. Now an error with compile                                'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0', a red line under the first line of code. It says that it needs the same version. Which version should I use?

Comment: Use 8.4 for the play-services one also?